# Razor Create Form for EF sub-object/navigation property collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor

Given an example object, say... `Entry` with a related object `Comment` where there is a foreign key from `Comment` to `Entry` called `EntryID` and is a collection (any number of comments for an entry), if a Razor page has a model of `Entry` and I want to have a form to *create* a new `Comment`, how would I do this? The scaffolded code is below and it would seem maybe I would say something like `Comment.CommentText` but that's not working because `Comment` is a collection...

```
//Code above this shows the Entry object as read-only followed by existing Comments, 
//I'm trying to allow the user to create a new comment
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 
...       
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CommentText" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CommentText" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CommentText" class="text-danger"></span>
...
```

So what seems intuitive would be

```
<input asp-for="Comment.CommentText" class="form-control" />
```

but it's a collection so intellisense goes "Oh, this is a collection, here's some linq things and collection things."

How do?

Comment: You might want to work with a Viewmodel step that has your Entry as a property and has an additional property called NewCommentText for example. When posting the form back all you'd need to do is add this to the Entry accordingly. Don't forget to add EntryID as a hidden input in your form so you can access it in your HttpPost Action to process the new comment accordingly.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If it's a collection you'll need a select tag like so:

```
   <select class="form-control" asp-for="Comment" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Comment))"></select>
```

or

```
   <select class="form-control">
      @foreach(var c in Model.Comment)
      {
          <option>@c</option>
      }

   </select>
```

Updated-Insert New Comment
You'll have to do a post on the form like so:

```
 <form asp-action="ControllerMethodName" id="formId" asp-controller="ControllerName"
     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>     
     <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CommentText" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CommentText" class="form-control" id="commentText" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CommentText" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
 </form
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerMethodName (CommentViewModel model)
{
     await _svc.InsertComment(model); //_svc being your service layer=

     return RedirectToPage("./Index")

     //for return value

    var result = await _svc.InsertComment(model);

   return Json(result);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class CommentViewModel
 {

     public string CommentText {get; set;}
 }
```

If you want to return a value to your html page, use the ajax or post method like so:

HTML:

```
  $('#formId').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var comment = $('#commentText').val();

        $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("ControllerMethodName", "ControllerName")',
          type: "POST",
          data: {"CommentText": comment},              

       }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //data will be your return value

       }).fail(function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {

           //error handling
      });
   }
```

Comment: This would be code to display existing comments. I need to create a new one and pass `Comment` object to the controller.

Comment: I like where you're going with the Create code but I'd have to do a bit of extra work since there's already the `Entry` model being passed in and `CommentText` isn't a direct property (though I could add it to the model and make sure it's not mapped to avoid errors). I have an idea I might try first and if it doesn't work, I'll try a modified form of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most straight-forward answer is to create a partial using the `Comment` object as a model, render a partial passing in a partially populated new `Comment` object as a model to the page.

Main/Parent Page:

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_CreateComment",new Comment() {  Entry.ID = Model.Id}); }
```

Partial:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
//form fields
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
```